# add a custom web.config attribute to a pre-existing element

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-config, custom-controls

I have created Custom .NET controls, and I'd like to know if it's possible, how to add a custom attribute in the web.config when you add the reference to the control.

Currently it is:

```
    <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="FOO" src="~/Controls/FooControl.ascx" tagName="Bar" />
    </controls>
```

But what i'd like to do, is the following

```
    <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="FOO" src="~/Controls/FooControl.ascx" tagName="Bar" defaultVal="12" />
    </controls>
```

Briefly, I want to add a custom attribute to a .NET a default ConfigurationElement (controls.add in this case) element

I know I could pass it as an attribute when I create the control or add a key in the appsettings, but I'd like to stay away from that if possible.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: are you wanting to add that to the config file on the fly for example..? if so I have done something exactly like this using XPATH to update the .config file.. correct me if I am not understanding your question.. thanks

Comment: editing the config file will restart the web application.

Comment: editing the web/app.config at runtime is total bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The [TagPrefixInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixinfo.aspx) class, which is what the `tag` element maps to is sealed and does not provide any generic properties for this purpose.

If you do try to add additional properties, your application will break because asp.net will refuse to process it.

In addition, even if this was possible, it would be very difficult to see how the definition of the tag would map to the actual control that is placed on the page. I think that would get asp.net all twisted into knots trying to resolve that. This would be similar to trying to add an attribute to a `using` statement.

Based on your question, you know what most of the rest of the options open to you are.

About the only one that you didn't mention was adding a property to the actual control that is placed on the page using the tag, i.e.

```
<FOO:Bar ID="test" runat="server" defaultVal="12"></FOO:Bar>
```

Comment: I was doing that already. I just wanted a default value defaultVal attribute grabbed from config.

Comment: Sorry, you can add it elsewhere in config, just not in the tag line. Microsoft has locked it down pretty tightly. For giggles, I also tried adding a querystring parameter to the usercontrol path, but then asp.net complains it can't find the user control.

Comment: i tried that to :P. Thanks anyways, i guess ill just use some key

Answer (score 1):

you would do this on the control itself, not the web.configuration file. I believe there is a UI attribute you add, something like

```
[DefaultValue(1)]
public int Number {get;set;}
```

I could be way off, but it's something like that.
The other option is to set the value in the object's ctor

```
class MyControl : Control
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        Number = 10;
    }
}
```

the next two options are to create a section handler to parse the value from a custom configuration node or use app.config to set the default value.

Comment: I know that, but I want to grab that default value from the web.config control's section. So something like [DefaultValue(ConfigurationControl.DefaultNumberValue)]
public int Number {get;set;}